# Clarification on math expression using prefix increment operator and bracket precedence

Tags: java, math, operator-precedence, associativity

Given this code:

```
int p,k=8;
p=k*(++k-8);
System.out.println(p);
```

when `++k` is evaluated `k=9` and then that becomes `k*(9-8)` giving `9*1`

```
int p,k=8;
p=(++k-8)*k;
System.out.println(p);
```

But this gives 9 as output

Comment: In my IDE it prints 8 , at the end of the program `p=8` and `k=9`. @Harsh which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Precedence is not the same as evaluation order. [Java always evaluates left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). Precedence specifies how those evaluations are combined.

Comment: 'This' being what? A correct Java compiler should produce 8 here. You have stated you get both 8 and 9. Which is it? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If parenthesis has a higher precedence then why is increment operator solved first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219423/if-parenthesis-has-a-higher-precedence-then-why-is-increment-operator-solved-fir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the class file your code compiled:

```
   int k = 8;
    byte var10000 = k;
    int k = k + 1;
    int p = var10000 * (k - 8);
    System.out.println(p);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a multiplication with

```
left side:  k  
right side: (++k-8)
```

As you correctly stated, braces have precedence. However, your program still runs "from left to right". So first the left side is evaluated, which is `k = 8`. Afterwards the right side is evaluated, which is `(++k-8) = 1`.
Now we have determined both sides and can multiply them together: `8*1 = 8`.

Comment: I agree  but his output was “9”.

Comment: @aomerk no. the question reads, why not 9?

Comment: i really thought that his ide messed up pretty bad